# Qmlscene dummydata

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.4

I have this qml:

**`main.qml`**:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Item {
    property alias text: t.text
    anchors.fill: parent
    Text {
        id: t
    }
}
```

What must I put in the [`dummydata`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qmlscene.html#loading-test-data) directory to show `Hello` on the text item?

Comment: Please, see qt documentation: [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qmlscene.html)

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that existed.

Comment: Yeah, never heard. Cool stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the property alias, but here's an example that works:

**`dummydata/myDummyData.qml`**:

```
import QtQml 2.0

QtObject {
    property string text: "Hello"
}
```

**`main.qml`**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Text {
        text: myDummyData.text
    }
}
```

Comment: The property alias is needed, because the text property is called from C++. Thanks for your response, but isn't valid, it must to assign the text property.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, in that case. As far as I can see, the whole point of `dummydata` is to expose properties to `main.qml`. You're not using any properties from a QML file in `dummydata`.

Comment: You can't assign to properties in `main.qml` like that. It's the other way around: only `main.qml` knows about the QML in the `dummydata` directory.

Comment: And yes, the answer is valid, according to your question.

Comment: If you run this code, main.qml will give an error, because myDummyData doesn't exists, only exists in the context of qmlscene. The reason to the dummydata directory exist is to simulate some values that will be assigned on runtime, and this is my question, how to assign the property text with the dummydata simulation. On the QT documentation is very clear using a model, but haven't any reference on how to do in other cases.

Comment: So you have a `dummydata` directory in the same directory as `main.qml`? And that `dummydata` directory contains `myDummyData.qml`? And the QML in your two QML files matches the code in my answer? And you run `qmlscene main.qml`? If you're doing all of those things and still getting an error, we'll need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the response is to change the approach, like is discussed on qtcentre, [qmlscene dummydata](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/63264-qmlscene-dummydata?p=280374&highlight=#post280374) question, so I'll rewrite my code.